# After installing Python3.7 -> "A problem occurred when checking for the updates"

Tags: apt, python, python3, python-2.7

I recently installed Python3.7, and after that a red icon (stop sign) appears in my task bar with the message  "A problem occurred when checking for the updates".

As far as I could inform myself, some link for Python is missing, and now everything is a mess among versions of Python in my computer.

When I do `python -V` I receive `python3.7` as output, and when I type `python3 -V`, I also receive `python3.7`.

After typing `sudo update-alternatives --config python` I obtain the following:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python2.7   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   1         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         manual mode
```

After typing `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` I obtain the following:

```
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.6
Nothing to configure.
```

I just want by Python default, the version Python2.7, and by Python3 default, Python3.7. The others versions of Python, if I can remove them and are not needed is better.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Try to run `python3`, which version do you get, 3.6 or 3.7?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that system tools (like apt ?) rely on python3.6 so you can't (or not advise) to change the default python3 version

Comment: When I run `python3` and open the python editor, it gives me 3.7. If I do `python`, it gives me also 3.7.

Comment: You haven't given us your version of Ubuntu, but the default `python` should be 2.7, otherwise system tools that use python (and need 2.7) will/could fail, and your system will have become unstable. I'd look at your `history`, and ensure you haven't created problems for yourself (which you'll discover in time) and back them out.  (My 18.04 shows 4 'apt' reverse-deps on python (2.7) along with many hundreds of others...).  `python` needs to reply 2.7

Comment: My version is 16.04....how can I come back to the default 2.7?